# What tools can I use for PDF indexing?

Tags: file-search, indexing, recoll

In our working group we used Recoll on a Ubuntu PC to index all the PDF. For a while we moved everything to a Redhat server. Is there a Recoll alternative which doesn't requires a GUI adn support searching through a web interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Recoll from the [command line](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.SEARCH.COMMANDLINE.html) if you want so.

Answer (score 3):

Recoll has a web interface, where you index on the server and search using a web browser:

https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui